# Extjs: Color parts of a sprite in a line series with different colors

Tags: extjs, charts, extjs4

I am using Extjs Charts and specifically line series to acheive my req.

I have a requirement of coloring different parts of a sprite ( for a single series ) with different colors based on a value of particular attribute.

For example i have 2 Services, Service1 and Service2 represented on Yaxis and the X-axis is the Numeric axis from 0 - 12.

I want to color Service1 Green from 0 -1 ( of x-axis ) and red from 1- 2 ( of x-axis )

I have tried using the renderer attribute for a sprite, but its called only once when a sprite is rendered as a whole, but i want to color parts of the sprite.

Is that possible using extjs charts. If so how can i achieve that.

```
 {
           type: 'line',
               xField: 'hour',
               yField: 'srvdata',
               showMarkers: false,
               style: {
                    stroke: 'green',
                    'stroke-width': 2,
                    fill: 'green',
                    //opacity: 0.2
                },
                /*renderer: function(sprite, record, attr, index, store) {
                    console.log(record);
                    return Ext.apply(sprite, {
                        fill: 'red',
                        stroke: 'red'
                    });
                }*/
      },
```

> [image]

Comment: Any suggestions to above are appreciated as i am completely stuck.

Answer (score 0):

One thing for sure, you cannot change the line color in this way.

```
renderer: function(sprite, record, attr, index, store) 
{
    // By changing sprite.fill or stroke, you are just changing the color of your point
};
```

Not sure how exactly to change line's color, I am stuck with that problem too. But I know that `surface : Ext.draw.Surface` needs to be changed. Like try to add `sprites` via **`chart.draw.Surface.add(sprite)`** function.